# Error running Ruby on Rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, version

while running Ruby on Rails program i got an error as follows,

```
"3168"
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:1
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from ./script/server:3
    from -e:2:in `load'
    from -e:2
```

The environment that i am working on is Windows xp and the configurations are,

Ruby 1.8.7 [i386-mingw32]

Rails 2.3.11

Gem 1.8.8

rake 0.8.7

sqlite3 1.2.1

Mongrel 1.2.0.pre2

Comment: can you provide me with your gemfile.Edit it in your question if possible

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
require 'thread'
```

into your boot.rb file.